# Concurrency in Rhapsody statecharts: state actions vs transitions

Tags: rhapsody, statechart

In IBM Rhapsody's statecharts, are there situations where a transition between state A and state B could happen before the actions in state A finished their execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UML and in Rhapsody actions cannot be interrupted - only behaviours (actions are atomic). So even if you have an interrupt-able region in an activity diagram you cannot stop an action in the middle - you can only interrupt the activity and make the control flow "jump" out of that region.

What you could do is create a behavioural classifier on the entry action or call an operation with an activity diagram and then send an event to interrupt its behaviour.

Comment: Just to make sure I get this right:  if in state A the entry action calls an operation that takes a long time to execute (say a "forever" loop, for the sake of the argument), if the transition from A to B is meant to be triggered by an event and the event does kick in, then the operation is interrupted and the statechart advances from state A to state B?